# python lambda, filtering out non alpha characters

Tags: python, lambda

i'm trying to keep only the letters in a string. i am trying to do something like this:

```
s = '1208uds9f8sdf978qh39h9i#H(&#*H(&H97dgh'
s_ = lambda: letter if letter.isalpha(), s
```

this errors out. how would a working version look?

Comment: Existing answers solve your problem, but you should probably read [this](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk), since you seem to be misunderstanding lambda syntax.

Comment: The purpose of your question is unclear. Are you looking for the simplest approach to solve your problem, or are you specifically trying to use a lambda function in order to learn how they work?

Comment: @nmichaels: actually, you probably shouldn't recommend that link to beginners. Using `lambda` with `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, etc. are increasingly frowned upon in favor of list comprehensions and generator expressions.

Comment: @Seth: Fair enough. Generator expressions are pretty awesome. How about [this](http://diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) one?

Comment: @mark: both actually -- i am unfamiliar with lambdas so i'd like to see that used in a solution and at the same time it'd be good to know the simplest solution.

Comment: @tipu: It's pretty hard to make a solution to this that uses a lambda since all the obvious approaches don't need one. It's best to ask one question precisely than two questions vaguely. If you need two precise answers, post two questions.

Comment: @nmichaels: I'm not trashing lambdas, which can be quite clear and useful (for example, using the `key` argument in `sorted`). I just think that people who are new to Python often don't realize there are more transparent and easy alternates to lambda, map, reduce, etc., (I was one of them) so it's better to not confuse them.

Answer (score 5):

Alternately:

```
s_ = filter(lambda c: c.isalpha(), s)
```

Comment: ...which, as others have pointed out, could be written `filter(str.isalpha,s)`, again obviating the use of lambdas. :)

Comment: Also, it should be noted that this will not work with Python 3 (see comments on Mark Byers's answer).

Answer (score 4):

how about

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','', s)
```

or

```
"".join([x for x in s if x.isalpha()])
```

Comment: +1 for the re solution is faster than the other solutions posted here (this has been timed many times in other questions)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a lambda function:

```
result = ''.join(c for c in input_str if c.isalpha())
```

If you *really* want to use a lambda function you could write it as follows:

```
result = ''.join(filter(lambda c:str.isalpha(c), input_str))
```

But this can also be simplified to:

```
result = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, input_str))
```

Comment: Note that this would result in a list, not a string.

Comment: @Amber: err… At least with Python26, that's not true =\ `filter(None, "asdf") ==> "asdf"`

Comment: @David Wolever: My comment was made regarding an earlier version of this answer which did not use `filter`.

Comment: @Mark: Why the change to `''.join(...)`? Are there versions of Python for which `filter` doesn't return a string?

Comment: @David Wolever: Python 3 returns a "filter object".

Answer (score 3):

One handy way to manipulate strings is using a generator function and the `join` method:

```
result = "".join( letter for letter in s if letter.isalpha() )
```

Comment: This only answers half the question.

Comment: @Mark: Now that the question has been amended to say he really does care that it uses lambdas, true. I therefore amend my answer with, "Lambdas are the wrong tool for this problem."

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a list comprehension here:

```
s_ = [letter for letter in s if letter.isalpha()]
```

However, this will give you a list of strings (each one character long). To convert this into a single string, you can use `join`:

```
s2 = ''.join(s_)
```

If you want, you can combine the two into a single statement:

```
s_ = ''.join(letter for letter in s if letter.isalpha())
```

If you particularly want or need to use a lambda function, you can use `filter` instead of the generator:

```
my_func = lambda letter: letter.isalpha()
s_ = ''.join(filter(my_func, s))
```

Comment: `[letter if letter.isalpha() for letter in s]` is not valid syntax. What you meant to write is `[letter for letter in s  if letter.isalpha()]`. `map` is not useful here either, you want `filter` ...

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel Oh wow, this is probably the worst answer I've ever given. Thanks for picking me up on that - I've fixed it now. Time to go recheck the rest of my code from pre-8am this morning...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = '1208uds9f8sdf978qh39h9i#H(&#*H(&H97dgh'
>>> ''.join(e for e in s if e.isalpha())
'udsfsdfqhhiHHHdgh'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of the long way round, but will let you create a filter for any arbitrary set of characters.

```
import string

def strfilter(validChars):
    vc = set(validChars)
    def filter(s):
        return ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch in vc)
    return filter

filterAlpha = strfilter(string.letters)
filterAlpha('1208uds9f8sdf978qh39h9i#H(&#*H(&H97dgh')  # -> 'udsfsdfqhhiHHHdgh'
```