# How do you filter a string to only contain letters?

Tags: python

How do I make a function where it will filter out all the non-letters from the string? For example, `letters("jajk24me")` will return back `"jajkme"`. (It needs to be a for loop) and will `string.isalpha()` function help me with this?

My attempt:

```
def letters(input):
    valids = []
    for character in input:
        if character in letters:
            valids.append( character)
    return (valids)
```

Comment: @pst: I agree with you 100%, but note that OP specifically said "needs to be a for loop."

Comment: Nontrivially, ``` "你好".isalpha() ``` return True. So, if u deal with word corpus in NLP, use reg.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If it needs to be in that for loop, and a regular expression won't do, then this small modification of your loop will work:

```
def letters(input):
    valids = []
    for character in input:
        if character.isalpha():
            valids.append(character)
    return ''.join(valids)
```

(The `''.join(valids)` at the end takes all of the characters that you have collected in a list, and joins them together into a string. Your original function returned that list of characters instead)

You can also filter out characters from a string:

```
def letters(input):
    return ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, input))
```

or with a list comprehension:

```
def letters(input):
    return ''.join([c for c in input if c.isalpha()])
```

or you could use a regular expression, as others have suggested.

Comment: `isalpha` returns a `boolean` and you check if it is `in letters`?

Comment: @ted -- Edited too quickly; didn't remove the 'in letters'

Comment: no need of LC, use just : `''.join(c for c in input if c.isalpha())`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- absolutely; then it's a generator expression insead. I just didn't want to have to get into a 'what's a generator?' discussion :)

Comment: if for loop is not a requirement, then the question is exact duplicate of another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097092/python-lambda-filtering-out-non-alpha-characters

just mentioning..

Comment: @IanClelland I always use a LC only in cases where I want to use the returned list, but here the returned list is only used by `join()`, so better use generators.

Comment: @IanClelland I noticed that my questions are getting negative ratings and I am unable to ask anymore questions. How can I make my question satisfy the guidelines of stackoverflow? I am new here and looked at the faq's and I edited my other posts to make it reflect the guidelines better but to no avail of my ratings.

Answer (score 10):

```
import re
valids = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z]+", '', my_string)
```

**EDIT:** If it needs to be a for loop, something like this should work:

```
output = ''
for character in input:
    if character.isalpha():
        output += character
```

Answer (score 4):

See [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html?highlight=match#re.sub), for performance consider a `re.compile` to optimize the pattern once.
Below you find a short version which matches all characters not in the range from `A` to `Z` and replaces them with the empty string. The `re.I` flag ignores the case, thus also lowercase (`a-z`) characters are replaced.

```
import re

def charFilter(myString)
    return re.sub('[^A-Z]+', '', myString, 0, re.I)
```

If you really need that loop there are many awnsers, explaining that specifically. However you might want to give a reason why you need a loop.

If you want to operate on the  number sequences and thats the reason for the loop consider replacing the replacement string parameter with a function like:

```
import re

def numberPrinter(matchString) {
     print(matchString)
     return ''
}

def charFilter(myString)
    return re.sub('[^A-Z]+', '', myString, 0, re.I)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method string.isalpha() checks whether string consists of alphabetic characters only. You can use it to check if any modification is needed.
As to the other part of the question, pst is just right. You can read about regular expressions in the python doc: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html
They might seem daunting but are really useful once you get the hang of them.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use `isalpha`. Also, `valids` can be a string.

Here you go:

```py
def letters(input):
    valids = ""
    for character in input:
        if character.isalpha():
            valids += character
    return valids
```

Comment: No need for all the extra `()`

Comment: I wish there was a pybeautifier.

Answer (score 0):

**Not using a for-loop.** But that's already been thoroughly covered.

Might be a little late, and I'm not sure about performance, but I just thought of this solution which seems pretty nifty:

```
set(x).intersection(y)
```

You could use it like:

```
from string import ascii_letters

def letters(string):
    return ''.join(set(string).intersection(ascii_letters))
```

**NOTE:** 
This will not preserve linear order. Which in my use case is fine, but be **warned**.