# How can I sanitize a string so that it only contains only printable ASCII chars?

Tags: python, string, io, ascii

I want a function which will sanitize a string. The string returned by the sanitizer should only contains what would be ASCII character #32 (space character) through ASCII #126 ('~').

ASCII character #9 (tab character) is to be replaced by four spaces. All other illegal characters are to be replaced by empty strings. For example, "\n" will be replaced with the empty string. We do not want illegal characters replaced by strings representing the relevant escape sequences. For example, we do ***not*** want a newline character replaced by a backslash character and an 'n' character.

It is fine if the final string is Unicode-encoded, instead of ASCII. I just want the only allowed characters to be as follows:

```
" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

EXAMPLE USAGE:

```
unsafe_string = "\u2502\u251cAPPLES\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\r AND \n\nBANANAS"
safe_string = sanitize(unsafe_string)
print(safe_string)
```

OUTPUT:

```
APPLES                     AND BANANAS
```

#### EDIT:

The following attempted solutions do not work because they fail to filter out new-line characters.

```
import string
import re

unsafe_string = "\u2502\u251cAPPLES\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\r AND \n\nBANANAS"

safe_string = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', unsafe_string) 
print(safe_string)    

printable = set(string.printable)
safe_string = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in printable, unsafe_string))
print(safe_string)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you filter a string to only contain letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400272/how-do-you-filter-a-string-to-only-contain-letters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

def sanitize(s):
    s = s.replace("\t", "    ")
    return re.sub(r"[^ -~]", "", s)
```

`[ -~]` means 'everything in the range from  (space) to `~`'. Adding `^` at the beginning means everything except that.

The output is:

```
APPLES                     AND BANANAS
```

In your example output, you forgot to replace tabs with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the characters, get codepoints, and check against allowed values:

```
def sanitize(unsafe_str): 
    allowed_range = set(range(32, 127)) 
    safe_str = '' 
    for char in unsafe_str: 
        cp = ord(char) 
        if cp in allowed_range: 
            safe_str += char 
        elif cp == 9: 
            safe_str += ' ' * 4 
    return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', safe_str)
```

**Example:**

```
In [1042]: unsafe_string = "\u2502\u251cAPPLES\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\r AND \n\nBANANAS"                                                                                                                             

In [1043]: def sanitize(unsafe_str): 
      ...:     allowed_range = set(range(32, 127)) 
      ...:     safe_str = '' 
      ...:     for char in unsafe_str: 
      ...:         cp = ord(char) 
      ...:         if cp in allowed_range: 
      ...:             safe_str += char 
      ...:         elif cp == 9: 
      ...:             safe_str += ' ' * 4 
      ...:     return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', safe_str) 
      ...:      
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [1044]: sanitize(unsafe_string)                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[1044]: 'APPLES AND BANANAS'
```

The last `re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', safe_str)` chunk is to compress whitespaces to one. If you don't want that only do `return safe_str`:

```
In [1046]: def sanitize(unsafe_str): 
      ...:     allowed_range = set(range(32, 127)) 
      ...:     safe_str = '' 
      ...:     for char in unsafe_str: 
      ...:         cp = ord(char) 
      ...:         if cp in allowed_range: 
      ...:             safe_str += char 
      ...:         elif cp == 9: 
      ...:             safe_str += ' ' * 4 
      ...:     return safe_str 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [1047]: sanitize(unsafe_string)                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[1047]: 'APPLES                     AND BANANAS'
```

---

FWIW, this generates the allowed list on each run of the function, but as it's a constant you can put it at the module level to have it generated only once e.g.:

```
ALLOWED_RANGE = set(range(32, 127))
```

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense to replace tabs with 4 spaces and then collapse them to one, so I doubt OP wants that.